# How to send file stream with file name and file extension using NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, stream

I'm using nodejs to send file streams to express response

```
var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);
fileReadStream.pipe(res);
```

The problem is, on the front-end, the file is downloadable only with the "download", and without extension. And this makes the file unable to use (as no extension).

Comment: Adding `Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="FILENAME"` header to your response should do the trick.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

please add this header before sending the response(replace the filename according your need):

```
 var fileReadStream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);  
 res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=YOUR_FILE.EXTENSION');
 fileReadStream.pipe(res);
```

Comment: hey, would you please guide me how to pass dynamic fileName.extension in header. ```      res.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + fileName);
```, this line is giving error ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION

Comment: Hm, are you setting this headers multiple times?

Comment: try this:
res.setHeader('Content-disposition', 'attachment; filename=\`${myfilename}\`');

Comment: Nope, it's not working. And I'm only setting header one time.

Comment: could you please remove that and see if it solves the issue?